# Should I put local/custom directories first or last on my path?

Tags: linux, shell, path

If I (a regular user) have, for example a `~/bin`, with executables in it, should that go first or last on my `PATH`? why?  Is there a standard/conventional approach under Linux?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/252338/potential-issues-with-adding-usr-local-sbin-to-roots-path) indicates that for root, you'd want to append (or better yet not even modify the path), but the logic might be different for a regular user.

I remember reading a recommendation once, but don't remember what it said.  Putting my custom path first ensures that I get the executables that I've bothered to construct and install.  Putting it last, ensures using system versions, which seems to have security advantages.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking us for.  You've already pointed out a (the main) reason why it can matter where you put your directory in the path, so you seem to know why you may want to put them first or last; whether you "should" or not is up to you and your situation.

Comment: Is there a (Linux) community standard that favors one over the other?

Comment: Probably not, but what difference does it make if there was?  What actual problem are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes, I always recommend that people put custom directories at the end of $PATH unless there is a need to have $PATH rewritten a specific way (service accounts, etc...).

If you intend on putting custom directories at the beginning of your $PATH, please ensure that permissions on those directories are such that they are secure (meaning these files will always contain what you expect without other people being able to modify them) especially if you intend on running any of these files with root -- or any other user for that matter.

Comment: What's "more secure" about putting them at the end, other than to ensure system-added locations will be checked first?

Comment: typically, normal users cannot modify binaries in the default path to create a potential for terrorizing your system. if you were to have 700 or 500 access on your binaries in ~/bin, then only you would be able to run those files and only you (and root) would be able to modify those files, thus you can rely on the code being what you wrote and not what you remember writing (as with 760, others in your group could modify the file and cause you to run something you were not expecting)